# Multiple click events on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, click

How do I achieve click on a link button on 1 page (say index.html), and when it navigates to the other (say dream.html), click a button on that page too, using Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Put a Jquery Script in page "**dream.html**" that clicks on your link when page load like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass parameter in url and if exist that parameter trigger works for you.

your Url

```
http://dream.html?sent=yes
```

Check for param

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

If exist :

```
var param = getUrlParameter('sent');
    if(param !== '')
     $('#dreampageID').trigger("click");
```

**Note : Do this inside document.ready and don't forget to include jquery librery.**

getUrlParameter taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)